# AWS - Hashicorp Vault - Passing Customer Credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, hashicorp-vault

We have a workflow in AWS that pulls twitter related data through API. We are doing it for over 100 twitter accounts and we expect the number to increase exponentially. Each twitter account has its own API key and so we want to use each key to pull data relating to that twitter account.

Our worklow previous used AWS secret but we only stored one account before but because we are planning to run it dynamically for separate accounts using their own API keys, we are thinking of using Hashicorp vault to store

We are wondering if anyone can point to best way we can enable the integration ? Is this the best approach or is there other scalable approach?

Answer (score 0):

Hashicorp provides a Lambda extension as a way to integrate with Vault

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/aws-lambda

This AWS blog post also details other options in the space and their advantages / disadvantages

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/choosing-the-right-solution-for-aws-lambda-external-parameters/